# Integrating dynamic programming into recursive solution

Tags: c, performance, recursion, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am trying to apply dynamic programming to the following problem:

"A robot is located in the top-left corner of an m x n grid. The robot can only move down or right at any point in time. The robot is trying to reach the bottom-right corner of the grid. How many unique paths are there?"

I have a recursive solution to this which I think works fine. However, it is slow:

```
int uniquePaths(int m, int n)
    {
        if (m==1 || n==1)
        {
           return 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            return (uniquePaths(m,n-1)+uniquePaths(m-1,n));
        }
    }
```

I can see that it would be useful if we were able to save the outputs of the uniquePath calls since many will be done more than once. One idea I have on how to achieve this is to create an m x n array and store then outputs in there. However, this would mean I would need to input the array into my recursive function and I think for this problem I am only allowed to input two integers. Is there a simple way to apply this?

Comment: You should be able to solve it by combinatorics. All paths will have `n-1` steps to the right and `m-1` steps down (assuming `m` rows and `n` columns). The total number of steps is `m+n-2` and any choice of `m-1` of those steps will be down. So the number of valid paths is the number of ways of choosing `m-1` from `m+n-2`. (This will be the same value as the number of ways of choosing `n-1` from `m+n-2` due to symmetry.)

Comment: This is slow because it is using impossible-to-optimize recursion. Use a loop instead.

Comment: Ok, I will try both a loop and a combinatoric route. What makes the recursion impossible to optimise?

Comment: The compiler typically can only unroll recursion if it is so called "tail call", meaning there should ideally only be one recursive call, at the end of the function. Checking this function in gcc, it is able to unroll it, but the generated machine code is horrible still. clang doesn't manage to unroll it. And this is exactly why we shouldn't teach recursion in school.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You may be interested to see the solution threads to https://projecteuler.net/problem=15 or https://leetcode.com/problems/unique-paths/description/.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to input the array as a function argument. It can be a local variable.

### The naive way: using a recursive function

If you really want to use a recursive function, you can declare the array in `uniquePaths`, then call another function which will use the array and do the calculations.

```c
int uniquePaths_helper(int *grid, int m, int n, int i, int j);

int uniquePaths(int m, int n)
{
    int *grid = malloc(m * n * sizeof(int));
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < m * n; ++k)
    {
        grid[k] = 0;
    }
    return uniquePaths_helper(grid, 0, 0, m, n);
}

int uniquePaths_helper(int *grid, int m, int n, int i, int j)
{
    if (grid[i * m + j] == 0)
    {
        if (i == n - 1 || j == n - 1)
        {
           grid[i * m + j] = 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            grid[i * m + j] = (
                uniquePaths_helper(grid,m,n, i+1, j)
                + uniquePaths_helper(grid,m,n, i, j+1)
            );
        }
    }
    return grid[i * m + j];
}
```

### Being smarter: filling the array in the correct order

In the previous solution there was a lot of overhead because we had to initialise the array with default values, then at every recursive call we need to check whether the value has already been stored in the array or needs to be calculated.

You can shortcut all that. Fill the array directly using your formula on the cells of `grid` rather than on the arguments of recursive calls.

The formula is: `grid[i * m + j] == grid[(i+1) * m + j] + grid[i * m + j+1]`.

The only tricky part is finding out in which order to fill the array, so that this formula can be written as a simple assignment, replacing `==` with `=`.

Since the value in a cell only depends on values with higher `i` and `j` indices, we can simply fill the array backwards:

```c
int uniquePaths(int m, int n)
{
    int *grid = malloc(m * n * sizeof(int));
    int i,j;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        grid[i * m + m-1] = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        grid[(n-1) * m + j] = 1;

    for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        for (j = m - 2; j >= 0; --j)
        {
            grid[i * m + j] = grid[(i+1) * m + j] + grid[i * m + j+1];
        }
    }
    return grid[0];
}
```